# Нет действий при нажатий на кнопку python, telebot

Tags: python, telebot

При нажатие на кнопку зарегистрироваться - всё работает,но при нажатие на кнопку 'qwe', ничего не происхожить, if не срабатывает, как исправить?

code:

````
from telebot import types
from db.database import create_account
from config import TOKEN

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


sub = 'default'
id = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_cmd(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регестрация", callback_data = 'register')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Для чего нужна регестрация? Что нужно для неё?⁉", callback_data = 'qwe')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Привет, я бот который скачивает видео с YouTube!\n Для начало работы нажми на кнопку <b>'Регестрация'</b>.",
                     parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: True)
def register(callback):
    id_user = callback.message.chat.id
    if callback.data == 'register':
        try:
            create_account(id_user, sub)
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Вы успешно зарегестрировались!")
        except:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Произошла ошибка, попробуйте позже.")

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: True)
def faq(callback):
    if callback.data == 'qwe':
        print('good!')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, '1. При регестрации мы получаем ваш <b>ID</b>, он не несёт ни какой конфиденциальной информациию\n'
                                                   '2. Для приобретения подписки <b>(ПОДПИСКА ПРИОБРЕТАЕТСЯ ПО ЖЕДАНИЮ)</b> и её выдачи нужен ваш <b>ID</b?',
                         parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя обе функции ловят все call-запросы, поэтому до второй не доходят, попробуй написать декораторы так

для регистрации

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['register'])
```

для qwe

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['qwe'])
```

а вообще можешь сделать один обработчик

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['register', 'qwe'])
def process_register_qwe(call):
    if call.data == 'register':
        # твой код register
    else:
        # твой код qwe
```

Comment: raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unclosed end tag at byte offset 335, всё равно ошибка(

Comment: ошибка пишет о том, что у тебя где-то не закрыт html тег, в функции qwe вывод сообщение 2 пункт в конце не закрыл тег, а поставил вопрос и её выдачи нужен ваш <b>ID</b? <- вот тут